# Rename EF6 Identity tables issue when UserId type changed to Int

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I was following that article to change UserId to int
http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/extensibility/change-primary-key-for-users-in-aspnet-identity#mvcupdate3

All went good and I had made that change but I want to do someting more, I want to rename tables as well.

In order to do that extnded `OnModelCreating`

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);           
        }
```

with

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Accounts").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Accounts").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
            modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");


        }
```

And then when I am generating the migrations (add-migration) I had an error:

```
Refinery.Web.Models.IdentityUserLogin: : EntityType 'IdentityUserLogin' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
Refinery.Web.Models.IdentityUserRole: : EntityType 'IdentityUserRole' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
IdentityUserLogins: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserLogins' is based on type 'IdentityUserLogin' that has no keys defined.
IdentityUserRoles: EntityType: EntitySet 'IdentityUserRoles' is based on type 'IdentityUserRole' that has no keys defined.
```

My entities looking like that:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser <int, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim> 
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("UserId")]
        public virtual List<Option> Options{ get; set; } 

        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser, int> manager)
        {
            // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
            // Add custom user claims here
            return userIdentity;
        }

    }

    public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<int> { }
    public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<int> { }
    public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<int> { }

    public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRole() { }
        public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
    }

    public class CustomUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, int,
        CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public CustomUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }

    public class CustomRoleStore : RoleStore<CustomRole, int, CustomUserRole>
    {
        public CustomRoleStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    } 

public class Option
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
    }
```

May be some one can help?

> I didnt have such issue with renaming Identity tables this way unless I changed
>   the UserId type to int.

Comment: Try telling EF what the keys are. For example modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUser>().ToTable("Accounts").HasKey<int>(l => l.UserId).Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");  Repeat for others.

Comment: @SteveGreene Getting conversion types error in such case. HasKey<int>(l => l.UserId) saying that I.UserId string and cant be int

Comment: There is another overload without the type HasKey(I => I.UserID).

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that while you have implemented your custom Identity models, you are still referencing the original identity models in the `OnModelCreating` method

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("Accounts").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogins");
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
    modelBuilder.Entity<CustomRole>().ToTable("Roles");
}
```